# Array reduce error - A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'homeScreen.dynamicHeroCarousel.0.externalUrl'

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my reduce method I am trying to set the `externalUrl` prop, is the condition is met, however, I get the error:

> Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'homeScreen.dynamicHeroCarousel.0.externalUrl'.

```
  const filteredCarouselItems = allCarouselItems?.reduce(
    (acc, carouselItem) => {
   
      if (carouselItem.cardType === 'mobileMechanic') {
        const url = carouselItem.externalUrl
          ?.replace('{vrn}', smrDetails?.vrn?.toString() || '')
          .replace('{postCode}', smrDetails?.postCode?.toString() || '');
    

        carouselItem.externalUrl = url;
      
      }

      return [...acc, carouselItem];
    },
    [] as CarouselItem[],
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `mutating` the state by reassigning the `url`.

```js
carouselItem.externalUrl = url; // mutating the object
```

**To fix it**, You have to construct a new object instead of mutating the existing one.

```js
const newCarouselItem = { ...carouselItem, externalUrl: url };
```

Then return the new object.

```js
return [...acc, newCarouselItem];
```